# Getting EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver after removing http-listener from standalone.xml in Wildfly Server

Tags: wildfly

**Wildfly Server Version:** - 9.0.1

**Project Type::** - WAR and EJB

**Description**: - We have developed a war project which uses EJB for DB transaction and works properly with both HTTP and HTTPS.

**Problem description**: - As we have removed following line 
    `<`http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" max-post-size="1717986920"/>
 from standalone.xml, so remote EJB applications are not connecting. We have tried almost all the attribute in remote utlity for external lookup but everytime we are getting same **Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: EJBCLIENT000025: No EJB receiver available for handling.** Even though, we have configure all the required properies in "jboss-ejb-client.properties" but stil problem is same.

After removing "http-listener", the server is working absolutely fine because we are able to use war application and also able to use EJB from war application which is running by https url. But remote utilities are not running.

Please let me know if any more settings are required in standalone.xml or on utility side including jboss-ejb-client.properties. Because it seems that some https related settings required on Utility side.

Following Settings Applied on Server: - In order to remove each HTTP configuration, we applied the following configuration

||---From--||

```
<management-interfaces>
 <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
    <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
</http-interface>
</management-interfaces>
```

||---To--||

```
<management-interfaces>
<http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
     <socket-binding https="management-https"/>
</http-interface>
</management-interfaces>
```

||---From--||

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
<socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
<remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

||---To--||

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
<socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
<remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

||---From--||

```
<server name="default-server">
<http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https" max-post-size="1717986920"/>
<https-listener name="httpsServer" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" max-post-size="1717986920"/>
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
<access-log pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access"/>
<filter-ref name="server-header"/>
<filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
</host>
</server>
```

||---To--||

```
<server name="default-server">
<https-listener name="httpsServer" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm" max-post-size="1717986920"/>
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
<location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
<access-log pattern="common" directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access"/>
<filter-ref name="server-header"/>
<filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
</host>
</server>
```

||---From--||

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
<socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
<socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
<remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

||---To--||

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
<socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
<socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
<socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
<remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

### **jboss-ejb-client.properties**

```
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port=8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connection.default.username=alice
remote.connection.default.password=abc123#
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Make your remote ejb calls over https?

Comment: Hi Will, I tried but not able to achieve in wild fly server. I will be really thankful if you can share some helpful links.

Comment: Please show your client's `jboss-ejb-client.properties` file?

Comment: Hi Steve, jboss-ejb-client.properties section added.